# Multiplying by an irrational number in combinatorial problems

Tags: combinatorics, irrational-numbers

Everybody knows that the number of derangements of a set of size $n$ is the nearest integer to $n!/e$.

It is also widely known that the $(n+1)$th Fibonacci number $F_{n+1}$ is the nearest integer to $(1+\sqrt{5})F_n/2$ where $F_n$ is the $n$th Fibonacci number (with the lone exception that $F_2=F_1$).

It had escaped my attention until today, when I wrote [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/486774/fraction-of-ordered-sequences-among-all-sequences/486843#486843), that the number of sequences of distinct elements of a set of size $n$ (including those of length $0$) is the nearest integer to $n!e$.  (**Later note:** Provided $n\ge2$.)

How widespread is this operation of mulitplying by an irrational number and then rounding, in combinatorial problems?  Are there other standard examples?  Is there some general theory accounting for this?

**Postscript some hours later:** If I'm not mistaken, the sequence whose $n$th term is the nearest integer to $n!e$ satifies the recurrence $x_{n+1} = (n+1)x_n + 1$.

Comment: The Fibonacci number thing works for any recurrence sequence for which the characteristic polynomial has one root greater than 1 (in modulus), the other roots being less than 1 (in modulus). See PV-numbers.

Comment: Concerning the postscript, if $a_n=n!e$, then $a_{n+1}=(n+1)a_n$, trivially. Did you mean "nearest integer to $n!e$?

Comment: fixed ${{{{{}}}}}$

Comment: I've just posted a version of this question to mathoverflow: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/142446/multiplying-by-irrational-numbers-in-combinatorial-problems

Answer (score 3):

The number of paths from vertex $v_1$ to $v_2$ in a complete graph on $n$ vertices is $$\sum_{k=0}^{n-2}\dfrac{(n-2)!}{k!}=\lfloor(n-2)!e\rfloor$$

To see why note that $e=1+1+\frac{1}{2}+\frac1{3!}+\cdots+\frac{1}{(n-1!)}+\cdots$

So $\displaystyle e(n-2)!=\left(\sum_{k=0}^{n-2}\dfrac{(n-2)!}{k!}\right)+\frac{(n-2)!}{n-1!}+\frac{(n-2)!}{n!}+\cdots$

But the sum at the end is less than $1$ for $n\geq3$. (to see why see that the sum at the end is strictly less than the geometrc series $(n-1)+(n-1)^2+(n-1)^3+\cdots$ which is exactly $1$ when $n$ is $3$.